# Angular removeAt always remove last element from FormArray

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, formarray

I have following form. `arr` is a list of FormBuilder.

```
  get arr() {
    return this.form.get('arr') as FormArray;
  }


  this.form = this.fb.group({
      id: this.fb.control(''),
      name: this.fb.control('', Validators.required),
      arr: this.fb.array([], Validators.minLength(1)),
    });



  public removeArr(idx: number) {
    this.arr.removeAt(0);
  }
```

As you can see `this.arr.removeAt(0)`, I am trying to remove first `arr` from the list, but it always removes the last element. Even I change it to something else e.g `this.arr.removeAt(2)`, instead of removing the third element it removes the last element.

How can I remove any element given by `idx` instead of always removing the last element.

**Note:**

Looks like the problem is related to the trackby function.

```
<form *ngIf="form" [formGroup]="form">
  <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
    <mat-label>Name</mat-label>
    <input type="text" matInput formControlName="name" required />
  </mat-form-field>


   <div
        class="arr-row"
        *ngFor="let control of arrControls; let i = index; trackBy: trackByIndex"
        [formGroupName]="i"
      >

        <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
          <mat-label>Name</mat-label>
          <input type="text" matInput formControlName="name" required />
        </mat-form-field>


        <button mat-icon-button type="button" (click)="removeArr(i)">
          <mat-icon>delete</mat-icon>
        </button>

   </div>


</form>

   trackByIndex: TrackByFunction<FormControl> = (index, _) => index;
```

If I change trackby function to

```
   trackByIndex: TrackByFunction<FormControl> = (index, v) => v.value.id;
```

Then it works but not all of the elements has id, so I can not use id here.

Comment: Could you please create a demo for this, I don't see why this code wouldn't work...

Comment: Please check the note.

Comment: Please simulate this issue in stackbliz so that it is easy to debug.

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. Any solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
public removeArr(idx: number) {
   while (this.arr.length - 1 > idx) {
        const center = this.arr.controls[idx+ 1].value;
        this.arr.controls[idx+1].patchValue(this.arr.controls[idx].value);
        this.arr.controls[idx].patchValue(center);
        idx++;
      }
      this.arr.removeAt(subSpec.length - 1);
   }
```